# recordset.GetString in Access VBA Query returns an extra character after the result

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query that I execute through VBA in Access 2010. The result of the query should be AFR, but it returns AFR with an extra line below it. I have added the "'" character to make the extra line visible.

```
TempHold = rs.GetString
Debug.Print "'" & TempHold & "'"
```

Returns this:

```
'AFR
'
```

But should return this:

```
'AFR'
```

I have tried using the below code, but none of the If statements evaluate as True. The code should check for a " ", a vbNewLine, or vbCrLf character but none evaluate as true. Does anyone know of any additional characters that would result in a new line?

```
If Right(TempHold, 1) = " " Then
    TempHold = Left(TempHold, Len(TempHold) - 1)
ElseIf Right(TempHold, 2) = vbNewLine Or Right(TempHold, 2) = vbCrLf Then
    TempHold = Left(TempHold, Len(TempHold) - 2)
End If
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the field to get the actual field data, instead of dumping the entire recordset?

Comment: Unfortunately the same issue occurs, but I will start using the `TempHold = rs.Fields("SchemaBenefitACF").Value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
Asc(Right(TempHold, 1))
```

to get the Ascii character code.

Once you've found the character code (which, as you wrote in your comment, was 13), you can use your code to remove it:

```
If Right(TempHold, 1) = Chr(13) Then
    TempHold = Left(TempHold, Len(TempHold) - 1)
End If
```

In this case, you can also use `vbCr`, which is the same as `Chr(13)`.

Comment: My guess would be a carriage return character, because that's what's used as a row delimiter according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You are right @clum it was characer 13, or the carriage return. Question now is, how do I remove it from the end.

Comment: I edited my answer to show how to remove. You basically had it already in your question, almost.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get rid of the carriage return in my opinion is to stop it being created in the first place. This method is a lot tidier than having to remove the last character.

In the `.GetString` method there is a parameter for `RowDelimiter` which by default is set to be a carriage return. However you can change this to be whatever you want including a zero length string as follows:

```
rs.GetString(, , , "")
```

If you run your debug again with this code:

```
rs.GetString(, , , "")
Debug.Print "'" & TempHold & "'"
```

You will get this result:

```
'AFR'
```

Remember if you want something different to be placed between rows then just change the zero length string to whatever you need.